# Slow Webpack compilation with Angular 8 + Tailwind.css + LESS

Tags: css, angular, webpack, postcss, tailwind-css

I'm currently using Tailwind.css with an Angular 8 site originally set up with LESS. 
I've followed [this post](https://dev.to/seankerwin/angular-8-tailwind-css-guide-3m45) which walks you through the set up process when using SASS and just changed references to match those for LESS. This works and the Tailwind styling appears correctly but I've noticed significantly slower initial compilation time and compilation time after editing the `tailwind.config.js` (over a minute or so).

I see this message when it gets stuck:

`51% building 342/343 modules 1 active ...e_modules\postcss-loader\src\index.js??postcss!C:\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\src\styles.less`

Inside the `styles.less` file I have the required tailwind imports:

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

My webpack configuration is:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                options: {
                    ident: 'postcss',
                    syntax: 'postcss-less',
                    plugins: () => [
                        require('postcss-import'),
                        require('tailwindcss'),
                        require('autoprefixer'),
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Is this expected? It feels like I might be doing something wrong, I've read a few things in my searches saying `post-css` can slow things down a little. Any hints much appreciated

Comment: Hello, did you find a good setup for less and tailwindcss, I'm getting trouble with import and the compilation as you said is very slow.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63639695/how-to-configure-tailwind-css-with-angular-ng-zorro-antd-and-less

Comment: In the end I just used one of many setup blog posts I found (like https://dev.to/seankerwin/angular-8-tailwind-css-guide-3m45). The first build is slow but I've found incremental build speed is tolerable. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, for some reason I'm getting error on resolving imports in this project.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a preprocessor with Tailwind CSS.

It's no good idea, but you can if you want.

Because:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors/