# How to configure Tailwind css with angular, ng-zorro-antd, and less?

Tags: angular, webpack, less, tailwind-css, ng-zorro-antd

I'm trying to integrate `Taiwind CSS` in an `Angular` project using `ng-zorro-antd` and `less`.

I'm having an error:

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--15-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--15-3!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/styles.less)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: Failed to find './themes/index'
  in [
    /Users/iguissouma/idea/test-ant-less-tailwind/node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/style
  ]
    at resolveModule.catch.catch (/Users/iguissouma/idea/test-ant-less-tailwind/node_modules/postcss-import/lib/resolve-id.js:35:13)
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

A sample [project-repo](https://github.com/iguissouma/test-ng-antd-less-tailwind) built with `angular-cli` and added `ng-zorro-antd` `@nartc/tailwind-schematics` schematics.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please take a look at that repo maybe you find it useful - https://github.com/trungk18/jira-clone-angular

Comment: have you tried using ng-tailwind? https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-tailwindcss

Comment: @Stefan I was inspired by this project jira-clone-angular but it use plain css and not less.

Comment: @BrunoCerecetto I used @nartc/tailwind-schematics that provide an integration that shoud works but getting some trouble with less.

Comment: In general, I have also a problem with tailwind and scss + angular-material. I can not make any @import in the styles file because builds fail.

Comment: I like use this schematic: https://github.com/notiz-dev/ngx-tailwind

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for mentioning my jira clone project! You are right, I only imported CSS from ng-zorro in Jira clone but the new style I wrote using SCSS syntax. I remembered I had to also [include sass-loader](https://github.com/trungk18/jira-clone-angular/blob/master/frontend/webpack.config.js) inside the webpack configuration for that to work.

I downloaded your source code and get exactly the same problem.

I start added [less-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/less-loader) into the project as well. I think the less loader is necessary because if you only run through postcss-less, it won't be enough. They are not the same.

```
npm install less less-loader --save-dev
```

That's how it looks. The less option javascriptEnabled is taking from one issue from ant.

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-motion/issues/44

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              ident: "postcss",
              syntax: "postcss-less",
              plugins: () => [
                require("postcss-import"),
                require("tailwindcss")("./tailwind.config.js"),
                require("autoprefixer"),
              ],
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "less-loader",
            options: {
              lessOptions: {
                javascriptEnabled: true,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

It went through the buld process but it took almost 10 minutes, see the five hundred thousands milliseconds on the screenshot. Not sure why It took so long. Have you found another better solution?

[image]

Comment: thank for your reply, after some research I came with a webpack.conf.js like yours too (with javascriptEnabled: true), but the build is very very slow and some time it hangs, and when it was success somehow tailwind is not working.

Comment: How dis you import tailwind? [at]import 'tailwindcss/base';  is not working -> tailwind/node_modules/tailwindcss/base.less doesn't exist so I used [at]import 'tailwindcss/base.css'; but the compilation hangs

Comment: I used the same less file that you gave on the repository with plain import "tailwindcss/base". Maybe the easiest is to append an extension .css like import "tailwindcss/base.css". I will test that and let you know

Comment: It is still hang  Let me give a bounty for this question

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use scss in your angular project and less only for ng-zorro theme style. then include both the styles.scss and theme.less files in the angular.json.

add those tailwinds in the styles.scss file and have the exact same webpack.config.js with @trungk18's jira clone project.

Basically, the solution is to let angular handle the scss and less style and your extra custom webpack only needs to handle the scss format for tailwind.